# Angular 6: How to protect route for account activation link

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I had a link which generate from back end to email:

> Ex: localhost/register/profile?id=39&token=IGCHSXtSzlHzGFsZPt

When the user clicks on the link user will redirect to profile page to edit. Before redirect to the page, I need to verify the token either It exists in the database.

I had api to verify the token:

> Ex:
>   localhost/registration/verifyConfirmationToken?id=39&token=IGCHSXtSzlHzGFsZPt

```
verifyToken(id:string, token: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('a', id).set('b', token);

    this.base_url = environment.MYAPI_REST_API_URL+"/registration/application/verifyConfirmationToken?a="+id+"&b="+token;
            return this.http.get(this.base_url)
            .pipe(map(user => {
                //return null if token not exist
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

The response if token exist (return null if token not exist):

```
{
"statusId": 4,
"createdBy": 0,
"creationTime": "2018-09-27 22:08:32",
"updatedBy": 0,
"updateTime": "2018-09-28 00:46:30",
"id": 39,
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"address": "noods",
"city": "bahyd",
"postcode": "70324324",
"active": true
}
```

The problem is if i put the link with random token, user still can view the profile page. How I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the CanActivate guard: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate